# When working on the cloud, how does one download files when curl or wget are not an option?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

Sometimes binary files can't be downloaded with `get` or `curl`. For example,

- let's say a colleague has shared a .zip file from his google drive.
- Or perhaps there is a download button that doesn't have a direct link to the file location so that the only way to get it is clicking on that button within a browser. Following redirects works sometimes, but sometimes not.

These are just a couple of situations that I've personally run into where I cannot access a file I need for work without downloading it first to my personal computer (which may not have space, or may have slow connection). Then I have to find a way to upload those files to a different location where wget or curl works so that I can get them onto my cloud instance and actually get to work.

One solution I thought of would be to find a way to run a browser on/through the cloud instances internet connection. I'm not sure if this capability exists or not.

Would this work? If not, what other solutions have people come up with?

Comment: What's your environment? If on compute engine, what's your OS? Why you can't install them with `apt install`?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I did not say that curl/wget were unavailable, I said that they will not work for certain applications. I was very clear about this in the first sentence of the question. I do hope that downvote was not yours.

Comment: No, I almost never downvote, if users take time to open an issue, it's because they are stuck! Anyway, sorry for my misunderstanding! And no, I haven't better answer than the current one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue in my own project.
I created an Ubuntu Instance, and I tried to download something from the internet without using `curl` or `wget`.
The only way I found to download something  is using a browser for the command line.
I tested many of them in order to check which of them could be better, and for me `links2` and `Elinks` are the best.
For this test, I shared a file from my Google Drive, I added the option to share with [Anyone with a link to the file](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en#link_sharing)

I installed Links2 with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install links2
```

To start it just type

`links2`

It will open a black screen then press `g` (or [esc] to see the menu)

[image]

Then paste the URL

`https://drive.google.com/uc?id=GOOGLE-DRIVE-FILE-ID&export=download`

[image]

Then save the file:

[image]

And then I was able to see the file in my Ubuntu:

```
MY-USER@INSTANCE-NAME:~$ ls -ltr
total 1540
-rw-rw-r-- 1 MY-USER MY-USER 1573568 Nov  2 19:23 SteamSetup.exe
```

Keep in mind that if the link works with Javascript you might have problems with the download.

In my case as the URL was public I was able to download the file but, I didn’t test with the authentication to Google.

Take in consideration that the url shared by drive is something like `https://drive.google.com/file/d/GOOGLE-DRIVE-FILE-ID/view?usp=sharing`

I just modified the URL to download the file to

`https://drive.google.com/uc?id=GOOGLE-DRIVE-FILE-ID&export=download`

Comment: Wow, thank you for going through that mini research project. Both interesting and helpful!